# should I use "worth of" here?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Are both forms of the below statements technically correct?

1. Webern wrote 6 hours of music.
2. Webern wrote 6 hours worth of music.

I'm not a native speaker, sorry for my english.

Comment: For *technically* correct, I would say no to the first because hours are not a measure of music. OTOH it is not true that Webern wrote 6 hours worth of music – much of his output was burnt and what remains can be played in about 6 hours.

Comment: @WeatherVane Excuse my pedantry but I think you mean his works were _burned_! I agree that the second version sounds better, but not with the explanation. Time _is_ one possible measure of music.

Comment: @TypeIA [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/burn) has: *verb (burned, British burnt).* Also *tempo* is more of a measure.

Comment: @WeatherVane I stand corrected on _burnt_: in AmE that's only an adjective. Tempo is another measure, sure, but not of extent. I'm not sure where you're going with that.

Comment: @TypeIA only that a composer's output isn't usually reckoned in hours.

Comment: I am British, and I would understand instantly that six hours' worth of music meant an amount of music that would take six hours to play. If someone were said to have dictated 24 pages worth of text I would understand that too, although I might ask what size the pages were, and what size the writing. They might just wave their notepad at me.

Comment: So is the first sence correct or not? Would you understand if I say "wrote 6 hiurs of music"?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I believe both are correct. Although ‘six hours worth of music’ makes more sense. If i were to write this sentence, I would say instead: ‘Webern wrote music for six hours’ as it is less confusing.

Comment: -1, "wrote music for six hours" means something different: it means he spent six hours writing music. The original means the total performance time of the music he wrote is six hours, but says nothing about how long it took him to compose it.